# React setState doesn't re-render after fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This code works if data already fetched.
But doesn't work if I refresh the page and doesn't rerender element.
I'm also using Next JS if it's worth mentioning.

```
class Books extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            book: []
        }
        this.renderBooks= this.renderBooks.bind(this);
    }

    renderBooks() {
        let item;
        let items = [];
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.props.ids.forEach(address => {
                firebase.database().ref(`/books/${address}`)
                    .on('value', snap => {
                        item = snap.val();
                    });
                items.push(item);
            })
            resolve(items);
        });
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            let res = [];
            res = await this.renderBooks();
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({ book: res });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return { book: 'err' }
              });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { <List grid={{ gutter: 16 }}
                        dataSource={ this.state.book }
                        renderItem={ item => (
                            <List.Item>
                                <Card title={ !!item && item.title }>
                                    ...Book content...
                                </Card>
                            </List.Item>
                        )} />
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Books;
```

Is there anything to know about setState and fetching data that I missed here?
PS. Edited constructor to book: [].

Comment: Why are you calling `this.renderBooks()` in the constructor and in `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: you should set book as `null`. When the response has come from `renderBooks` set the state which will then trigger a re render. You should call `renderBooks` in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

Comment: @Cameron Thank you for your remark! Actually I initialize the constructor with blank array [] due to the list layout requirements (Ant design).

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Thank you! Null gives 'Cannot read property 'length' of null' due to list rendering mechanics. Could you elaborate your idea about componentDidMount? (I've tried to invoke renderBooks for within this method numerous times...) Thank you!

Comment: @Igniter use an empty array instead of null - and see @jackjop answer below for how to use `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot initialize `book` with a promise. Instead you can have a solution like below.

Add a conditional rendering to you `render` method so it will know when to render `book`. Also you don't need to return `new Promise` in this case.

```
class Books extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { books: null }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.renderBooks()
    }

    renderBooks() {
        this.props.ids.forEach(address => {
            firebase.database().ref(`/books/${address}`)
             .on('value', snap => {
                this.setState({books: [...(this.state.books || []), snap.val()] });
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
           this.state.books ? 
            <div>
                { <List grid={{ gutter: 16 }}
                        dataSource={ this.state.books }
                        renderItem={ item => (
                            <List.Item>
                                <Card title={ !!item && item.title }>
                                    ...Book content...
                                </Card>
                            </List.Item>
                        )} />
                }
            </div> 
           : 'Initializing'
        );
    }
}

export default Books;
```

Promises are basically async functions that are resolved when it's time.

So when you do

```
 var item, items = []; // <---- Step 1
 this.props.ids.forEach(address => {
     firebase.database().ref(`/books/${address}`)
         .on('value', snap => {
             item = snap.val(); // <--- Step 3
         });
     });
     items.push(item); // <----- Step 2
 });
```

The steps are like this. So you were doing `items.push(item)` before item was assigned a new value which is `snap.val()`. And that makes `item` `undefined`.

I guess the second result you have is thanks to caching. If the internet connection is SOOOO FAST `Step 3` might be earlier than `Step 2`, but that's a bad assumption. That's why the second time you get the result correct.

In this answer's case, instead of having an `items` array, the `snap.val()` is added to this.state.books. But this makes it a bit heavyweight. Because every time a query `on('value')` is called, the `setState` method will be triggered and the component will be rendered again. If there were 1000 ids the state would change 1000 times.

That's why instead of getting the data one by one I would suggest you to get all the data at once. Try to google something like `'retrieve multiple data from firebase javascript'`. Unfortunately I don't know much about firebase so cannot help there.

Comment: use `componentDidMount` to call `this.renderBooks`, don't do it in the constructor

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald yeah just realized! thank you anyway

Comment: you had an error with `setState` - you needed to pass it an object

Comment: @jackjop Thank you for your time! Unfortunately your solution gives the same results. I have it screencasted for more clear explanation. https://i.imgur.com/g4a7kQj.gif. After full refresh of the page there are several undefined results as seen on the screen. After I edit e.g. <Card /> tag it shows actual results, since data was fetched previously.

Comment: @Igniter I see. Probably `on('value')` event is async. I changed my code. Please check again. Notice the changes in renderBooks method

Comment: @jackjop This is brilliant! Worked like a charm! `on('value')` is indeed a Firebase promise. Could you please describe the difference between your solutions? I can't clearily see what's going on in your code. Or maybe just give some reference to read. Thank you for your time again!

Comment: @Igniter I would suggest you to read about promises. It's a bit hard topic to really understand. But I'll edit my answer now to clear it as much as I can

Comment: @Igniter just added clarification. I hope this was clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing `this.state.book` with a promise. Try setting it to `null` instead:

```
this.state = {
    book: null
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It gives "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at List.render". This is how Ant design list layout works. Actually I tried null/[]/'' in many variations.

Comment: Put the following at the top of your `render()` method: `if (!this.state.books) return null`. This will avoid any rendering while `this.state.books` is still `null`.